# Ajax returning a Zend_Form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

**Controller A:**

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
        ->setParam('noViewRenderer', false);
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$form = new Form_Targets();
$this->view->form = $form;
if(!isset($form)) $form = false;
```

**View A:**

```
<?php echo Zend_Json::encode(array('form' => $this->form));?>
```

**Controller B:**

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
        ->setParam('noViewRenderer', true);
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

        $form = new Form_Targets();
        $this->view->form = $form;
        if(!isset($form)) $form = false;
        echo Zend_Json::encode(array('form' => $form));
```

View B:

```
Blank
```

**View script where Ajax Returned:**

```
<div id='paz'>
    <p>Ello</p>
    <p>Ello</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#available').bind('change', function (e) 
    {
        $.getJSON('<?php echo $this->baseURL()?>/admin/ajax/target-year/year/' + encodeURIComponent($('#available').val()),
        function(data) 
        {
            alert(data);
            $("#paz").html(data.form);
        }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Response A:

```
{"form":{}}
```

Reponse B:

```
{"form":{}}
```

The problem is the form is not being returned...

Comment: Why you are using JSON? Maybe just send pure HTML and then you can just paste HTML to your website.

Comment: Problem is that when I use pure HTML, the getJSON function doesn't work and alert() is not run, should I use the $.ajax function instead...I tried it and it didn't even make the ajax call...maybe my syntax was wrong

Comment: Try this -> `Zend_Json::encode(array('form' => $this->form->render()));` so you actually have something in JSON.

Comment: That worked: used `Zend_Json::encode(array('form' => $form->render()));` in the controller...thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

Just to not leave thread without answer:

Form has to be rendered in order to be able to encode it into JSON:

```
Zend_Json::encode(array('form' => $this->form->render()));
```

without `->render()` array had form object instead of it's HTML representation.

Usually people use `$this->form` to render form, forgetting that it uses magic method `__toString()` to render form.